# Try & Except Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

So I am trying to make a calculator on python, and am getting an error saying "'continue' not properly in loop"

Here is the code:

```
try:
  num1m = int(input("Select the first number --> "))
except ValueError:
  print("That's no number!")
  continue
try:
  num2m = int(input("Select the second number --> "))
except ValueError:
  print("That's no number!")
  continue
num3m = (num1m * num2m)
str(num3m)
print("The sum is " + num3m + ".")
```

Can someone help me out, thanks :)

Comment: Continue is a keyword for loop do do next iteration.

Comment: If you're trying to use "continue" as a command to go back a few lines and ask the user to re-enter their number, this may be useful to you: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482)

Answer (score 3):

You can't just use [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) wherever, there is syntax to follow:

> `continue` may only occur syntactically nested in a `for` or `while` loop, but not nested in a function or class definition or `finally` clause within that loop. It continues with the next cycle of the nearest enclosing loop.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, `continue` must be used within a loop. One way you could make your code work

```
while True:
    try:
        num1m = int(input("Select the first number --> "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That's no number!")
        continue
    try:
        num2m = int(input("Select the second number --> "))
    except ValueError:
        print("That's no number!")
        continue
    break
num3m = (num1m * num2m)
str(num3m)
print("The sum is " + str(num3m) + ".") # make sure to convert int to str
```